# Flatten Linq query of nested groupings with combined key in ASP.net

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, flatten

In my database there are player-objects which do have a nationality and points.

I need a possibility to nest my groupings. Because they are given by the client, grouping into an anonymous key seems no option here.
So I have to nest them like

```
Players.Where(p => p.Created <= /*some date*/)
    .GroupBy(p => p.Nationality) // group them by their nationality
    .Select(arg => new {
        arg.Key,
        Elements = arg.GroupBy(p => p.Points > 0) // group them by the ones with points and the ones without
    })
    . // here i need to flatten them by also combining the key(s) of the groupings to put them into a dictionary
    .ToDictionary(/*...*/);
```

At the end, the `Dictionary` should contain the keys as `string` like `["USA|true"]`, `["USA|false"]` or `["GER|true"]` with their respective elements.

I guess `SelectMany` is the key but I don't get the point where to start from to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

What about this [solution](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ankYnq):

```
public class Player
{
    public string Nationality {get;set;}
    public int Points {get;set;}
    public double otherProp {get;set;}

    //new field is added
    public string groupings {get;set;}
}

var groups = new List<Func<Player, string>>();
groups.Add(x => x.Nationality);
groups.Add(x => (x.Points > 0).ToString().ToLower());
Players.ForEach(x =>
    groups.ForEach(y => x.groupings = x.groupings + (x.groupings == null ? "" : "|") + y(x))
);
var answer = Players.GroupBy(x => x.groupings).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.ToList());
```

Comment: As stated in the question - grouping by anonymous is not an option. The group-by clause is build dynamically by a user(client) given value and cannot be converted as anonymous. e.g. the client sends `Player(Nation,HasPoints)` and this is converted into the group-by

Comment: @TimSchmelter this is how the `GroupBy` is build. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40420025/passing-dynamically-build-expression-to-groupby-not-working. As it is build dynamically from the given string `new {/*...*/}.ToString()` will not work here

Answer (score 0):

Answering your concrete question.

As you mentioned, `SelectMany` is the key. The place in your query is right after the `Select`:

```
.Select(...)
.SelectMany(g1 => g1.Elements.Select(g2 => new {
    Key = g1.Key + "|" + g2.Key, Elements = g2.ToList() }))
.ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Elements);
```

It can also replace the `Select` (i.e. start right after the first `GroupBy`):

```
.GroupBy(p => p.Nationality)
.SelectMany(g1 => g1.GroupBy(p => p.Points > 0).Select(g2 => new {
    Key = g1.Key + "|" + g2.Key, Elements = g2.ToList() }))
.ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Elements);
```

Comment: I currenty have `GroupBy(p => p.Nationality + "|" + p.HasPoints)` which works as expected as I now have only one key and the elements. Problem now is, how can I build the expression which is passed to the group-by? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40420025/passing-dynamically-build-expression-to-groupby-not-working

Comment: I know that post (because I closed it as duplicate), but don't see the relationship with this one. Here you are asking for flattening a provided query, so is doing the answer. If that's not your question, then post a question with the exact requirements, otherwise you are just wasting the time of the people trying to help you.